# Microsoft Graph API Filter Extension Properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to filter some user data on my Azure B2C Account.

I can get the filters working fine on a Built In Property but filtering on any of my extension properties returns no data.

For example I am filtering on VerifiedEmail as below

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=extension_{ID}_EmailVerified eq true`

Without the filter I get data back but with the filter applied no data is returned but there is users who have verified emails within the dataset.

I also tried including the extension field within the select query

Answer (score -1):

Try with the beta verison with the below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=extension_{ID}_EmailVerified eq true
```

APIs under the `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Comment: Tried that still no joy :-(.  Going to work round the issue for now but seems strange as the documentation I can find seems to imply this should work.

Comment: Strange.! I have created one custom user attribute and enabled to receive the attribute information for one of the signup policy. After assigning the custom attribute value i used the above query to fetch the information.

Comment: Can you check with the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the above query. Initially try to query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` only users info then use filter

Comment: Yeah I tried it there.  Ran the query against users got some details back.  Tried something simple like searching for `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=city eq 'Aberdeen'` that worked too but not my custom field.

Comment: what about the non beta version? it might not be available always